# Why changes in Checkbox's value are not displayed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using react and material ui. I need to get all checkboxes in a list checked by checking one checkbox in a parent component (i.e. I need to select all). I pass down the correct value of the parent checkbox via props, but that doesn't trigger visual changes in its children, even though their values do change to 'true'. I'm sure that the values are correct, because I tried logging them to the console.

Here's the parent:

```
const [checkboxValue, setCheckboxValue] = useState(false)

<Checkbox value={checkboxValue} onChange={e => setCheckboxValue(e.target.checked)}/>
{elements.map(element => (<Element selectAll={checkboxValue}/>))}
```

And here's the child:

```
function Element(props) {
    const [checkboxValue, setCheckboxValue] = useState(false)
    useEffect(() => {
        setCheckboxValue(props.selectAll)
    }, [props.selectAll])

return (
<Checkbox value={checkboxValue} onChange={e => setCheckboxValue(e.target.checked)}/>)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using `value` instead of `checked`

```
function SingleCheckBox({ selectAll }) {
  const [checkboxValue, setCheckboxValue] = useState(selectAll);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCheckboxValue(selectAll);
  }, [selectAll]);

  return (
    <Checkbox
      checked={checkboxValue}
      onChange={(e) => setCheckboxValue(e.target.checked)}
    />
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [checkboxValue, setCheckboxValue] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Checkbox
        checked={checkboxValue}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setCheckboxValue(e.target.checked);
        }}
      />
      <div>
        <h2>Other checkboxes</h2>
        <SingleCheckBox selectAll={checkboxValue} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-buck-yp7f3z?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Please vote up if it helped you :)

Comment: I did, but it says that I need to have a higher reputation for my vote to count here. But it also says that my upvote did have effect on your reputation. And now I also ticked the box to "accept the answer". I hope this has some effect too. Again, thank you for your help.